# IF-ELSE AND WHEN THEN Statement Difference in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

The below statement works perfectly

```
select case when person ="name1" then "nickname1"
when person="name2" then "nickname2" 
else person end as name
from person;
```

But it fails with IF ELSE of below statement

```
select if person ="name1" then "nickname1"
else person end as name
from person;
```

What are the differences between (IF-THEN-ELSE) AND (CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE-END)?
And one more is Do we have "CASE" statement for IF-THEN=-ELSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `CASE-IF-ELSE-END` does not exists.

It is not proper SQL.

From [CASE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

OR

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no CASE-IF-ELSE-END in MYSQL .

Check this out for [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You do not use CASE with IF-ELSE in MySQL.

[IF-ELSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

[CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)